# Haskell GUI library on OSX

Tags: user-interface, haskell

I want to create a GUI application on OSX with Haskell. It mainly should be about drawing on a canvas. I tried the following options but none of them worked:

- WX. It doesn't work well because of dependency on obsolete quicktime version. I can't compile with it and can't use it in ghci.
- Gtk2hs. It involves very complicated install process which fails for me with homebrew (I tried the sequence on haskell.org wiki but it didn't work for me probably because of OSX10.8).

Are there any other options?

Comment: Have you tried gtk2hs with macports gtk+?  That's always worked for me.  You only want to use macports for gtk+ though, not any of the Haskell stuff.

Comment: I managed to configure wx so that it works well :-)

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov: How did you manage to configure wx to avoid the quicktime problem?

Comment: @Conal I just reinstalled all the ws packages in cabal and it started to work fine. There are no errors about quicktime anymore. However, it still doesn't work from ghci.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov Thanks. What breaks in ghci?

Comment: @Conal I have some strange error messages. Here's gist with them: https://gist.github.com/3723396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just drawing 2D shapes on a canvas, you could try [gloss](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss).

Comment: The thing I need the most are good font metrics. OpenGL doesn't have them. However, the library is very nice. Thanks.